# Cordova can't find images in android run

Tags: angular, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

After I fixed the issue with Cordova not finding the main js files from my angular prod build, now it can't find the icons and images used.

My workflow: I created a Cordova folder in my folder with

```
cordova create cordova be.volckaertachiel.be "volckaertAchiel"
```

then:

```
cd cordova
cordova platform add browser
cordova run browser
rm -r www
cd ..
```

build it in the corodova folder with:

```
 ng build --target=production --environment=prod --output-path cordova/www/
```

changed the base path from `/` to `./`

And then ran it in the browser with `Cordova run browser`

After I changed my backend(node.js API) to accept port `8000` it ran like it was running in angular2

After this `Cordova platform add android` and then `Cordova build android`

it launched the Android SDK, it launched the app, showed me my login screen, logged in. now it throws errors all over the place.

[image]

Comment: check your config.xml file and check the path of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding the plugin [cordova-plugin-ionic-webview](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
```

I don't really know why, but it works.